# Select box open onclick direction -- display data both upwards and downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not too sure if this question qualifies for SO, perhaps borderline. If it doesnt kindly inform me and I'll modify accordingly.

Ive searched every corner of the intraweb for a library or tutorial for the following, but simply cant find one.

Im trying to display a select box, which onclick moves half the options upwards and half the options downwards as in the image below:

[image]

Ive seen a javascript library where instead of the default option where the data in a select box gets displayed downwards -- it gets display upwards.

However I cant find anything to achieve the effect on above where half the data essentially gets displayed in an upwards direction and other half in a downward direction.

If anyone can provide some input it would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Direction of the drop down also depends on the browser and available space.  If the dropdown is near the bottom of the window, the drop down will open upwards.  In IE10 or newer, it will try to keep the selected item in place, everything above will open upwards, everything below will open downwards.  However, for the default HTML select element, there is no author control over this behaviour.

Comment: For a richer custom widget, I suspect the implementation is non-trivial and not the kind of thing there would be a tutorial for.  If you tell us where that example is from, maybe somebody can inspect it to see if it uses a common library or is custom built.

Comment: One thing is for sure, that's not really an HTML select, as their display direction depends on the browser, not much you can do there. So you need to fake it by other means.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski I added a link to a page which uses this selectbox in question `www.superbru.com` after you do a quick register & sign in you should see it. (I am in no way affiliated with the site above)

Comment: Hey @FacundoCorradini thank you for your comment I added the link of the website for user Facundo as he requested. If you want to have a peek at the source code see my comment above.I had a look and tried to figure it out but it is above my skill set unfortunately :( Thanks

Comment: I signed up, but I don't know where that particular component is. :/ (Nevermind, I found it @ /sixnations/play_tipping.php)

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Thanks for taking the time to help. I believe you need to go tournaments and click to join a pickem tournament thus ->`tournaments ->  SixNations Predictor -> Page With Selectbox`

Comment: do you need it animated? or a "jump" appearance is OK?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini found it? Anything that resembles it would work, what ever is easiest... You managed to figure out that code, it looks insanely complicated!!

Comment: to be honest, I was already working on a solution for you and didn't feel like signing up :p check my answer bellow and see if that works for you, it's fairly simple pure CSS

Comment: It's custom written, so not using any components you'd be allowed to reuse. Which leaves you to re-engineer one yourself (or with some very generous help).  It's doing some simple maths setting the scroll of the body and the position of the component, etc.  But it lacks the keyboard controls of a native HTML select so has its shortcomings, too.

Answer (score 6):

If a jump-appear solution (instead of animation) is an option, you can get away with pure CSS an no javascript at all.

HTML select direction can't be controlled as it's up to each browser, but you could use instead radio buttons and control related labels.  Then it's just a matter of controlling the display of the labels on hover.

```css
html{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

input{
  display:none;
}
label{
  display:none;
  padding:1em;
  width: 300px;
}

input:checked + label{
  background:green;
  display:block;
}

#container{
  border:1px solid lightblue;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
}

#container:hover{
  transform:translate(-50%, calc(-50% + 2em));
}

#container:hover label{
  cursor: pointer;
  display:block;
  border-bottom:1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="radio" name="result" id="f2">
  <label for="f2"> France 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="result" id="f1">
  <label for="f1"> France 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="result" id="0" checked>
  <label for="0"> Draw</label>
  <input type="radio" name="result" id="i1">
  <label for="i1"> Ireland 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="result" id="i2">
  <label for="i2"> Ireland 2</label>
</div>
```

### Edit:

Apparently in my frenzy of "you can do that with pure CSS" I forgot it's 2018, and the above answer will only work for desktop and fail miserably on mobile, as it relies on :hover.
So we need a little JS, just to toggle an ".active" class instead of the hovers.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("#container label")
for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    labels[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      container.classList.toggle("active");
    });
  })(i);
}
```

```css
html{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

input{
  display:none;
}
label{
  display:none;
  padding:1em;
  width: 300px;
}

input:checked + label{
  display:block;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}

#container{
  border:1px solid lightblue;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
}

#container.active{
  transform:translate(-50%, calc(-50% + 2em));
}

#container.active label{
  display:block;
  border-bottom:1px solid lightblue;
}

#container label{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="radio" name="result" id="f2">
  <label for="f2"> France 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="result" id="f1">
  <label for="f1"> France 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="result" id="0" checked>
  <label for="0"> Draw</label>
  <input type="radio" name="result" id="i1">
  <label for="i1"> Ireland 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="result" id="i2">
  <label for="i2"> Ireland 2</label>
</div>
```

Got some issues there trying to apply the click event to the container instead of each individual label, so that JS can surely be improved... any help will be appreciated.

Alternatively, you can just use jQuery for that. Talkin 'bout "I forgot it's 2018"...

```
$('#container label').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
});
```

Comment: Holy Moly thats impressive!! Will this work on mobile as well...?

Comment: I am envious of your CSS skills!

Comment: @Marilee mobile doesn't have a hover state. You can skirt around it by having a checkbox and a label bound to said checkbox. Based on the checked state you toggle the items to be shown. Ex: `checkbox:checked ~ .container { /* show me here */ }`

Comment: Thanks @WildBeard much appreciated pal

Comment: @WildBeard im sorry if im missing this but are you saying the user would have to select a checkbox for the select element to open -- it doesnt sound very user friendly though :-/ or am I missing the point?

Comment: @Marilee in a round about way, yes. The label element would be styled to look like the above. When tapped, it triggers the checkbox's `:checked` state and you can use that as a CSS selector. I can make a fiddle as an example.

Comment: @Marilee see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nu8ccs7a/) as an example.

Comment: @WildBeard I got it! Thank you very much for taking the time to help!

Comment: @Marilee good catch.. kind of dropped the ball there. For mobile you'll still need to control the display of the labels on click events.

Comment: @WildBeard I don't see how the checkbox :checked hack will help here, if using a label for that checkbox as the container instead of a div, the labels stacked above it will prevent the clicks / tap from changing the checkbox

Comment: I provided a simple concept as an alternative method to reveal your items for mobile since hover won't work. The code would be almost entirely the same short of adding a hidden checkbox and a new set of mobile styles that trigger based on the `:checked` state.

Comment: will I get what you mean there, there the "clicks / taps" are already changing the "checked" status for the radio buttons (which in turn controls which label is displayed), you can't have it change both at the same time with plain CSS

Comment: @FacundoCorradini Ive got a bit of time to play around with this today at work so will tweak and experiment and update on progress. But essentially what you are saying is that @Wildbeards suggestion of using a selectbox toggling between `:checked` states wont work or wont be the ideal solution, some javascript code would need to be added... for optimal mobile performance...correct?

Comment: @Marilee yup. This method relies on showing the label for the selected (hidden) radio button as the "select" content. What Wildbeards suggest is a common hack to show/hide a div on click, which is great. But both techniques can't go together, as the click event would either be on the label for the radio button **or** the checkbox, as far as CSS goes. Can't get both change on a single click. So javascript is needed to make this work on mobile, by toggling on click a simple CSS class that changes the display of the radio button tags from none to block, similarly to what :hover does on desktop.

Comment: Quick question, what about simply changing on `:hover` to the `:active` event which is the closest css event to javascript `onclick()` which should essentially make your solution work for both desktop and mobile with the only difference being the element would have to be clicked / (tapped on mobile) to open, which is fine...? Or can you see some problems using `:active` event?

Comment: Problem is that :active ceases as soon as you lift the finger off the mouse. So the "select" will display the options when you click on it, but will disappear before you can click on on of them

Comment: DAMN!! alright back to the drawing board it is. Thanks Pal

Comment: well, with those upvotes guess I'll have to make the fallback for mobile happen lol :p

Comment: @FacundoCorradini a simple mobile fallback and 1) the bounty is yours 2) you can go to bed knowing you made someone very happy

Comment: @Marilee there, I just switched the pure CSS approach to an almost-pure one, just using JS to toggle an "active" class on click instead of the hover effects. Hope that works for you!

Comment: @FacundoCorradini and you just got rewarded by 100 of my rep. Thanks Pal

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can find a library which has this functionality built-in, you could resort to just manually change the position of the dropdown from pretty much any select library.

Here's a "simple" example using [select2](https://select2.org/):

```
var disableSelection = false, selectionDisabledTimer;
$('#example').select2({ //#example is a select element
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1 //disable search
}).on('select2:open', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
          var goUpBy = $('.select2-dropdown').height() / 2; //nr of px to move up
          $('.select2-dropdown')
            .removeClass('select2-dropdown--below') //remove style which hides upper border
            .css('marginTop', -goUpBy +'px');       //move dropdown up
    }, 0);
}).on('select2:opening', function(e){
    disableSelection = true;
    clearTimeout(selectionDisabledTimer);           //clear old timer (in case of multiple fast clicks)
    selectionDisabledTimer = setTimeout(function(){ //disable selection for 500ms
        disableSelection = false;
    }, 500);
}).on('select2:selecting', function(e){
    if(disableSelection){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/981usa95/7/

Note: The code looks messy because I had to work around the issue where, because the dropdown is opened below the cursor, the option below the cursor is instantly selected. Cleaner solutions may exist.

Comment: Hey Alexandru thanks for your input. Im using Chrome as soon as I release mouse button the navbar collapses, but I believe you stated that in your comment. I'll have a fiddle, Thanks!

Comment: @Marilee, Added a work-around by disabling clicking in positions that could trigger the select of the option below the cursor.

Comment: Hi Alexandru this looks pretty good, thank you! Is it possible that one could modify the dropdown that it opens when any part of the select element is clicked...? Instead of only opening when the small arrow icon is clicked. Apart from that this may be the best solution yet. Thanks

Comment: @Marilee. I added a different work-around so you may click anywhere now.